# Placemark Icons not showing up on Google Earth !!! Where I am going wrong?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I had developed an application where in the data fetches from our database and shows up different polygons on Google Earth by generating an kml file.

I was able to do all sort of things like showing polygons,showing up placemarks with name and description, but was unable to show up the icon image on polygons.

I have checked the kml in notepad and it is generating in correct format.

I don't understand where I am getting wrong,Why my placemark icon is not showing up in my Google Earth software.

Here I am posting my whole kml code.
You could copy it into a notepad and save it as kml.

Note:- Google Earth Software is installed in my computer, through which I view the downloaded KML File.
Please help me in this regard.
Thanking You.

Regards,
BhanuChandra

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
      <Style id="bsr">
         <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.5</scale>
            <Icon>
               <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
         </IconStyle>
         <LineStyle>
            <width>3</width>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
         </LineStyle>
         <PolyStyle>
            <color>51400FF</color>
            <LabelStyle>
               <color>7fffaaff</color>
               <scale>1.5</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
         </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Placemark>
         <styleUrl>#bsr</styleUrl>
         <name>Near Subbaraopally Village</name>
         <description><![CDATA[<b>Circle : </b>Adilabad<br/><b>Division : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Range : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Year : </b>2015<br/><b>Type : </b>Block<br/><b>Planting Method : </b>Labour Intensive(AR)<hr><br/><font color=LightSlateGray  size = 1>ID : 108</font>]]></description>
         <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
               <extrude>1</extrude>
               <tessellate>1</tessellate>
               <altitudeMode>ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND</altitudeMode>
               <outerBoundaryIs>
                  <LinearRing>
                     <coordinates>79.49749,19.02856,0 79.49763,19.02929,0 79.49739,19.02944,0 79.4979,19.0311,0 79.49628,19.03258,0 79.5002,19.0356,0 79.5007,19.0342,0 79.50138,19.03229,0 79.4997,19.03065,0 79.49749,19.02856,0 </coordinates>
                  </LinearRing>
               </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
         </MultiGeometry>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
         <styleUrl>#bsr</styleUrl>
         <name>Bamboo with Misc 5x5 Bamboo (2.5x2.5 Misc) 10 Ha Near Gangaram Nagar</name>
         <description><![CDATA[<b>Circle : </b>Adilabad<br/><b>Division : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Range : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Year : </b>2015<br/><b>Type : </b>Block<br/><b>Planting Method : </b>Semi Mechanical(AR)<hr><br/><font color=LightSlateGray  size = 1>ID : 350599</font>]]></description>
         <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
               <extrude>1</extrude>
               <tessellate>1</tessellate>
               <altitudeMode>ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND</altitudeMode>
               <outerBoundaryIs>
                  <LinearRing>
                     <coordinates>79.46981,19.07547,0 79.46986,19.07352,0 79.46985,19.07323,0 79.46861,19.07353,0 79.46556,19.07297,0 79.46554,19.07353,0 79.46607,19.07423,0 79.46693,19.07483,0 79.4679,19.0748,0 79.46785,19.07613,0 79.4698,19.07641,0 79.46981,19.07547,0 </coordinates>
                  </LinearRing>
               </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
         </MultiGeometry>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
         <styleUrl>#bsr</styleUrl>
         <name>Misc. Plantation at Waripet</name>
         <description><![CDATA[<b>Circle : </b>Adilabad<br/><b>Division : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Range : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Year : </b>2015<br/><b>Type : </b>Block<br/><b>Planting Method : </b>Labour Intensive(AR)<hr><br/><font color=LightSlateGray  size = 1>ID : 350782</font>]]></description>
         <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
               <extrude>1</extrude>
               <tessellate>1</tessellate>
               <altitudeMode>ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND</altitudeMode>
               <outerBoundaryIs>
                  <LinearRing>
                     <coordinates>79.43114,19.05873,0 79.43082,19.05947,0 79.43044,19.06048,0 79.42989,19.0615,0 79.42976,19.06282,0 79.42985,19.06278,0 79.43007,19.06333,0 79.4304,19.06406,0 79.43073,19.06469,0 79.43098,19.06514,0 79.43174,19.06511,0 79.43106,19.06442,0 79.43066,19.06397,0 79.43061,19.06345,0 79.43005,19.06156,0 79.43132,19.05964,0 79.4313,19.05883,0 79.43114,19.05873,0 </coordinates>
                  </LinearRing>
               </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
         </MultiGeometry>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
         <styleUrl>#bsr</styleUrl>
         <name>Misc. Plantation at VSS Waripet</name>
         <description><![CDATA[<b>Circle : </b>Adilabad<br/><b>Division : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Range : </b>Bellampally<br/><b>Year : </b>2015<br/><b>Type : </b>Block<br/><b>Planting Method : </b>Semi Mechanical(AR)<hr><br/><font color=LightSlateGray  size = 1>ID : 350783</font>]]></description>
         <MultiGeometry>
            <Polygon>
               <extrude>1</extrude>
               <tessellate>1</tessellate>
               <altitudeMode>ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND</altitudeMode>
               <outerBoundaryIs>
                  <LinearRing>
                     <coordinates>79.43598,19.06411,0 79.43665,19.0637,0 79.43723,19.06328,0 79.43742,19.06237,0 79.43725,19.06227,0 79.43741,19.06162,0 79.43762,19.06168,0 79.43788,19.06087,0 79.43873,19.05984,0 79.43935,19.05886,0 79.43988,19.05789,0 79.43965,19.05784,0 79.43924,19.05835,0 79.43835,19.05918,0 79.43786,19.05967,0 79.43732,19.06053,0 79.43686,19.06133,0 79.43709,19.06148,0 79.43687,19.06222,0 79.43647,19.06213,0 79.43648,19.06247,0 79.43614,19.0634,0 79.43954,19.05254,0 79.43944,19.05298,0 79.43923,19.05334,0 79.43926,19.05383,0 79.43931,19.05415,0 79.43893,19.05488,0 79.43867,19.05509,0 79.43887,19.05533,0 79.43886,19.05543,0 79.43893,19.05592,0 79.43939,19.05605,0 79.43974,19.05604,0 79.43945,19.05522,0 79.43949,19.05503,0 79.43952,19.05487,0 79.43948,19.05458,0 79.43948,19.05444,0 79.4395,19.05405,0 79.43958,19.05375,0 79.43974,19.05278,0 79.43975,19.05255,0 79.43598,19.06411,0 </coordinates>
                  </LinearRing>
               </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
         </MultiGeometry>
      </Placemark>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: [Your KML](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20151102.kml) is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary issue is to show an icon and label while using a polygon requires a Point to appear inside the MultiGeometry alongside the Polygon. If the placemark geometry is a polygon then an icon and label will NOT appear on the map - that needs a point.

Here is an example of such a geometry for the first placemark:

```
<MultiGeometry>
     <Point>
        <coordinates>79.49883,19.03208</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <Polygon>
       <extrude>1</extrude>
       <tessellate>1</tessellate>
       <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
             <coordinates>79.49749,19.02856,0 79.49763,19.02929,0 79.49739,19.02944,0 79.4979,19.0311,0 79.49628,19.03258,0 79.5002,19.0356,0 79.5007,19.0342,0 79.50138,19.03229,0 79.4997,19.03065,0 79.49749,19.02856,0 </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
       </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

There are also some minor errors in the KML. First, LabelStyle is inside the PolyStyle element. Next,the altitudeMode values are invalid: *ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND* must be changed to *clampToGround* .